# React native modal display super slow iOS but not Android

Tags: android, ios, performance, react-native

I'm building an app with React Native (RN 0.47). We use modals to display informations but it takes ages to open on iOS (Where it's super fast on Android). On iOS (iPhone 6) it takes around 3 seconds and on Android it's nearly immediate.

Investigations show that time is spent in the UI and not in JS.

My view is composed of more than 100 components and we don't really see how we can reduce this amount...

[image: Screenshot of the modal]

Components are only colored Views or Texts. The other tab is currently empty.

What can cause this difference between Android and iOS ?
What can be done to reduce this display time ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Is it only in simulator? If so you should have probably enabled the slow animations.
in simulator go to debug >> slow animations (Command + T)

Comment: No, it's also on device. And in fact in Simulator, it seems to be faster than on device.

Comment: Do you have redux logging enabled?

Comment: @Starchand No, it happens in production too...

Comment: Are those children controlled or uncontrolled components??? I mean, function components? to improve rendering speed.

Answer (score 0):

we found the issue. It was related to Sentry and react native: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/608

Be careful if you use React-navigation and Sentry !